# Table coming before appendix despite being placed in appendix section

Tags: floats

I am looking to have a table as the first item in my appendix but when the file is built the table is coming above the appendix.

So it builds as:

Table

Appendix Title

Appendix A

Where I want:

Appendix Title

Appendix A

Table

My code:

```
\section*{Appendix}
\appendix
\section{Dissemination Opportunities}
\begin{table}
\caption{Conferences}
\begin{tabular}{|p{17cm}|}
  \hline
  AMBIENT - The Fourth International Conference on Ambient Computing, Applications, Services and Technologies. \\
  \hline
  BHI - International Conference on Biomedical and Health Informatics. \\
  \hline
  CBMS - International Symposium on Computer Based Medical Systems. \\
  \hline
  Pervasive Health - International Conference on Pervasive Computing Technologies for Healthcare. \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Do you really want the tabular material to float? Put the material in a minipage along with `\captionof{figure}{Conferences}` provided py the `capt-of` package (or `caption` package or any KOMA-script class).

Comment: Setting `\begin{table}[b]` would be useful if you need a float.

Comment: @Johannes_B that kind of worked, it's now where I want it but there is about 3/4 of a page of white space between the appendix a title and the table

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To solve this I had to add `[h]` to my `\begin{table}`, like this:

```
\begin{table}[h]
```